# What determines the line width of Windows command processor redirected output?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, redirection, console

When redirecting standard output (to a file, via `>`) of an application launched from the Windows command line, is the line width determined by the application or by Windows?

As an example, I created a 268 character x 70 line console (CMD) window, and ran a CLI application.  The output used the entire console width of 268 characters, as expected.  But when I redirected the same output to a file, the maximum length of each line was 80 characters.

Which is responsible for this behaviour, applications or the Windows operating system itself?

Comment: Interesting. I would expect that there is no limit. I know this is not the case for powershell, in that case it takes the console width into consideration, and by altering that, you effectively change the output to a file even if you never print to console. I bet something similar is happening in cmd. You can try to use `mode con cols=268 lines=70` and see if it changes the behavior. This effectively resizes the command window but from the inside.

Comment: btw, this is the code for powershell in case you want to use that instead: `$pswindow = (get-host).ui.RawUI;
$newsize = $pswindow.BufferSize;
$newsize.Width=200;
$pswindow.BufferSize = $newsize;`

Comment: Perhaps edit your question with more details. Double check that your wrapping isn't caused by your text viewer line wrap length. FYI On my Windows CMD.EXE (display width 150chars) shows exactly the same line length with redirect `>` as without. I checked mine with 1000 char lines and used Linux `od -xc {file}` and searched for `n` to confirm the line wrap is 1000th char.